# X has 19 features, but MLPRegressor is expecting 100 features as input. MLPregressor SkLEARN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

this is the first time I ask a question on this platform. I'm using Sklearn's MLPregressor model to do the bike rental prediction. I need to test and verify the "RMSE" in the test base, however when I perform the prediction, this error is returned ( X has 19 features, but MLPRegressor is expecting 100 features as input).
The two dataframes (training and testing) were treated in the same way, and I've already verified that their features have the same names. I also tried to transform the format of the variables from pd.dataframe to numpy.ndarray and normalize the data with StandardScaler. but all my attempts lead to the same error. can anybody help me?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#------------------------------------------------
# Import of training and test data, already treated. The data were treated in the same way
caminho = '/content/treino_tratado.csv'
train = pd.read_csv(caminho)
train

caminho2 = '/content/teste_tratado.csv'
test = pd.read_csv(caminho2)
test.head(3)

#-----------------------------------------------------
#definition of my predictor variables and target variable
X = treino.drop('aluguéis', axis = 1)
y = treino['aluguéis']

# I chose to convert the x and y variables to np array. in the sklearn documentation it is shown that the variables must be in this format
X = X.to_numpy()
y = y.to_numpy()
#test data
test = test.to_numpy()

#----------------------------------------------------------
# model
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, random_state=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3 , random_state=1)

regr = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(1000,), activation='relu', solver='adam', alpha=0.0001, batch_size='auto', learning_rate='constant', learning_rate_init=0.001, power_t=0.5, max_iter=200, shuffle=True, random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=False, warm_start=False, momentum=0.9, nesterovs_momentum=True, early_stopping=False, validation_fraction=0.1, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, n_iter_no_change=10, max_fun=15000).fit(X_train, y_train)
predicoes = regr.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import math

mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, predicoes)

rmse = math.sqrt(mse)

print(rmse)
# output = 109.25977971042573
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# prediction in test database
predicoes2 = regr.predict(test)

# error -> X has 19 features, but MLPRegressor is expecting 100 features as input.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that this line is creating a new random dataset with the X, y variables?

```
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=200, random_state=1)
```

Why are you using it?

It creates a new dataset with 100 features, and that is probably the reason of your error.

Comment: THANKS Nohman, it was exactly that line of code that was wrong. I didn't realize I was using it.

Comment: @HenriqueRezerMosquér You are welcome. It would be nice to accept the answer if it solved your problem.